# Mocking props from HOC in react for snapshot tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I am trying to appropriately mock props for a simple sign out button component. The only prop in this component is the `firebase` prop which is coming from a Higher Order Component (HOC) called `withFirebase`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';

const SignOutButton = ({ firebase }) => (
  <button type="button" onClick={firebase.doSignOut}>
    Sign Out
  </button>
);

export default withFirebase(SignOutButton);
export { SignOutButton as SignOutButtonTest };
```

My thought was that I could export the functional component without the HOC and mock the `firebase` prop directly and pass that to the component for the snapshot test.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import SignOutButtonTest from '../SignOutButton';

describe('SignOutButton Tests', () => {
    it('renders with some data', () => {
        const props = {
            firebase: {
                doSignOut: () => {},
            }
        };
        const tree = renderer.create(
            <SignOutButtonTest {...props} />
        ).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

However, when I run this test I get the following `TypeError`. Any thoughts on how to properly mock this `firebase` prop for a snapshot test?

```
  ● SignOutButton Tests › renders with some data

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'doSignOut' of null

      3 | 
      4 | const SignOutButton = ({ firebase }) => (
    > 5 |   <button type="button" onClick={firebase.doSignOut}>
        |                                           ^
      6 |     Sign Out
      7 |   </button>
      8 | );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use named export instead of default export. Here:

```
import SignOutButtonTest from '../SignOutButton';
```

you are still importing HOC'ed version.

It should be:

```
import { SignOutButtonTest } from '../SignOutButton';
```